# how to remove a field from dynamic attributes table if value is blank means?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am using **gem dynamic attributes** for dynamically creating header and values for one table

additional_fields is a model where i am using dynamic attributes

```
class AdditionalField < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_dynamic_attributes :destroy_dynamic_attribute_for_nil => true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

in additional field table in **dynamic_attributes** column all the data will be stored in  hash like

```
{"field_blood_group" => "B positive","field_age" => "22"}
```

while creating if value is blank for any field means it wont get added to table
but the problem is while editing the user and updating if i remove the value for those fields means it is not getting removed from the table and it is saved in database like

```
{"field_blood_group" => "B positive","field_age" => ""}
```

instead i want to remove the field having null value and it should be stored as

```
{"field_blood_group" => "B positive"}
```

i don't know how to do this i got struck in this 
can any one help me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i find a solution for this

before updating the table now i am checking whether the value is blank or not if the value is blank means i am replacing the value by nil and its getting removed from the database

```
params[:additional_field] = {"field_blood_group" => "B positive","field_age" => ""}

for field in params[:additional_field]
 field[1] = field[1].blank? ? nil : field[1]
 @user.additonal_field.update_attribute(field[0],field[1])
end
```

but still i am confused about this working principle bcoz while creating i am not checking whether its value is blank or not

while creating it is not getting created in database if value is null means.after creating if we remove the value means its not removing from database so i am manually giving null for the value now its getting removed

it will be useful
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting an empty string from your interface and since that is `!= nil` the gem will keep it. You could try to do something like:

```
after_validation do |record|
  dynamic = record.methods.each do |m| 
    if has_dynamic_attribute?( m ) and record.read_attribute( m ) == ''
      record.update_attribute m, nil 
    end
  end
end
```

do it in the `after_validation` callback since the gem is doing its magic with nil attributes in a `before_save` hook. Read more about [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

EDIT: more generic after feedback from questioner.

Comment: it wont be like field age alone will come as nil always user can add n number of fields like this i have to check all the field whether its nil or not and i have to update that table thats what the problem for me

Comment: indeed - see update that deals with this. Pros: won't need to list all fields (can mixin from generic module if you have many models). Cons: loops through all methods on model which will be a tiny bit slower than doing it explicitly.